# Regular Expression strings in Java

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to use a regular expression that extracts a substring with the following properties in Java:

1. Beginning of the substring begins with 'WWW'
2. The end of the substring is a colon ':'

I have some experience in SQL with using the Like clause such as:

```
Select field1 from A where field2 like '%[A-Z]'
```

So if I were using SQL I would code:

```
like '%WWW%:'
```

How can I start this in Java?

Comment: I would like to do this in Java

Comment: LIKE only performs simple pattern matching using the wildcards `%` and `_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("WWW.*:");
   Matcher m = p.matcher("zxdfefefefWWW837eghdehgfh:djf");
   while (m.find()){
       System.out.println(m.group());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match only word character and `.`, then you may want to use the regular expression as `"WWW[\\w.]+:"`

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("WWW[\\w.]+:");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("WWW.google.com:hello");
    System.out.println(m.find()); //prints true
    System.out.println(m.group()); // prints WWW.google.com:
```

If you want to match any character, then you may want to use the regular expression as `"WWW[\\w\\W]+:"`

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("WWW[\\w\\W]+:");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("WWW.googgle_$#.com:hello");
    System.out.println(m.find());
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Explanation: `WWW` and `:` are literals. `\\w` - any word character i.e. a-z A-Z 0-9. `\\W` - Any non word character.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different example using substring.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "http://www.google.com:80";
    String substring = example.substring(example.indexOf("www"), example.lastIndexOf(":"));
    System.out.println(substring);
}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go for known substrings and delimiters.  Much more efficient than compiling the regular expression.  Watch out for case-sensitive searching and other unplanned inputs (i.e. leaving off the port; the string `http://www.google.com/` will throw an error here).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right

```
String input = "aWWW:bbbWWWa:WWW:aWWWaaa:WWWa:WWWabc:WWW:";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("WWW[^(WWW)|^:]*:");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
WWW:
WWWa:
WWW:
WWWaaa:
WWWa:
WWWabc:
WWW:
```